# get result for jquery confirmation to return in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I need to convert from a javascript `confirm` into utilizing jquery ui confirmation dialog.  Problem is, where I need to call and open the confirmation dialog - I need to return a true/false based on what button a user click (OK/Cancel).  I know javascript is asynchronous , but I'm stuck how to do this?  can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#dialog:ui-dialog').dialog('destroy');

        $('#confirm-delete-quote').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                OK: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    callback(true);
                },  
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    callback(false);
                }   
            }   
        }); 

        $('div.multiRowCheckboxMenu').checkboxMenu({
            menuItemClick: function(text, count) {
                $('#confirm-delete-quote').dialog('open');
//                return confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + text + ' the selected ' + count + ' quote(s)?');
// HOW DO I RETURN WHAT THE USER CLICKED IN THE DIALOG HERE?
                return callback();
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: I did not understand your question? what's you need to convert from comfirn to a jquery ui dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You have started off correctly, except that you cannot expect to have a return value.

The native `confirm()` is a blocking script. That is to say, the execution thread waits for the user's input. Which is why you can return a value.

However, while using a custom dialog, you need to move the code for whatever you intend to do with the return value into the callbacks for `Ok` and `Cancel`.

```
     buttons: {
            OK: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(true);

                //You know user clicked true, so do something here itself
            },  
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(false);

                //Similarly here
            }
```

Comment: ya I knew the JS is asynchronous, my problem is the plugin I'm utilizing which calls the function `menuItemClick` then submits or prevents a form from submitting.  Wasn't sure how, without duplicating that code, to work with this.

clickReturn = opts.menuItemClick.call(this);

if(clickReturn) {/* do something */}